# Is there ever a reason to explicitly Import-Module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module, import-module

I was just reading the PowerShell [Modules](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109225551/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878284(v=vs.85).aspx) guide page and I noticed a line on the `Import-Module` section:

> The following actions trigger automatic importing of a module, also
> known as "module auto-loading."
>
> - Using a cmdlet in a command. For
>   example, typing Get-ExecutionPolicy imports the
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Security module that contains the
>   Get-ExecutionPolicy cmdlet.

So given that, why should we ever care about using `Import-Module`? Isn't it always taken care for us automatically? In what case would I need to explicitly write out `Import-Module`?

Comment: When the said module is not in a path recognized by powershell.. like some custom folder it may be in.

Comment: @VikasGupta But it also says `"Windows PowerShell searches for the specified module within the directories specified in the PSModulePath variable"`, so clearly powershell already knows of its existence

Comment: I assume that is why VikasGupta specifically said "some custom folder" so as to indicate something *not* in `PSModulePath`.

Comment: @EtanReisner from what I understand you cant set a custom folder, can you? Hence  the explicit "will search in PSModulePath"

Comment: You can `Import-Module ../relative-path/to/module.psm1` though.

Comment: @EtanReisner Ah, didnt realize

Comment: Also, as indicated on that link, the auto-loading feature is PowerShell 3.0+ functionality so, presumably, you need it in older versions.

Comment: A bunch of the commands I have to run on servers don't work unless I import the relative module, particularly for IIS and Server Management (such as features and roles).

Don't know about it doing it automatically but it doesn't in my case.

Comment: There is no such variable in the context of PowerShell: _"in the PSModulePath variable"_ It is so written in mentioned doc, but the doc further down correctly says: _"in the value of the PSModulePath environment variable."_ A variable starting with `PS...` looks like a PowerShell variable, which adds to the confusion and a waste of time when someone is trying to `$PSModulePath = "C:\..."` which is wrong and correctly is `$env:PSModulePath`. [Another microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.1) after MSDN removal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`Import-Module`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725.aspx) in the following cases :

- The module file is not in a path included in `$PSModule` Path
- You have different modules with the same name but in different paths
- The module is already loaded and you want to reload it after making modifications to it. (with -Force)
- To import only specific cmdlets, functions or variables from that module (with the `-Cmdlet`, `-Function`, and `-Variable` parameters respectively)
- To prevent loading cmdlets or functions from the module that would overwrite the commands with the same name and are already loaded in the current session ( with `-NoClobber` )
- To add a prefix to the nouns of the cmdlets in this module ( with `-Prefix`)
- To import a module from a remote computer (with the `-PSSession` parameter )

The list is not totally exhaustive but these are the main use cases for the [`Import-Module`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725.aspx) cmdlet.

Comment: Interesting how most of the scenarios listed above are descriptions for various parameters `Import-Module` has :) Not surprisingly, one could / should include a link to the documentation as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but I wanted to add my two cents.

- To explicitly document the dependency of a script upon a module
- If  $PSModuleAutoloadingPreference is set to "none", modules need to be explicitly loaded.  You don't know if users have turned this off or not.

Comment: Excellent point. I ran into this with someone that wanted to use a module I wrote but had AutoLoading off. Took me longer than I care to admit to figure it out.